# How to put the greatest value from others columns in another column - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with Oracle SQL.
i need to stock the greatest value of multiple columns, in a new total column. I know that i can do it with function "GREATEST", but when i execute my UPDATE, i get errors like 'the request get multiple row' and even if i add "rownum <= 1", i get nothing !

What i have to do on my update? Thank you !!

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

and this is my request (that not working)

```
    UPDATE my_table set total= 
(
select greatest(col_1, col_2, col_3) from mytable
);
```

Comment: You have to add a where condiiton to the select where you compare the ID

Comment: Confusing... do you have two tables or just one? [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Because your inner query really returns multiple rows. How the DBMS should know which row from the resultset you need?

Comment: is the total column already in the table or you have to create it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a sub-query:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET total = GREATEST(col_1, col_2, col_3);
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (col_1, col_2, col_3, total) AS
SELECT 5, 0, 4, -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 1, -1 FROM DUAL;
```

After updating, then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Outputs:

> | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
> | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

---

If you really want to use a sub-query (I don't see why you would) then you can correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
UPDATE my_table t
SET total = ( SELECT GREATEST(col_1, col_2, col_3)
              FROM   my_table m
              WHERE  t.ROWID = m.ROWID );
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99e90/2)*

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the exact above requirement:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table   
(col_1 NUMBER,
col_2     NUMBER,
col_3 NUMBER);

INSERT INTO my_table (col_1,col_2,col_3) VALUES(5,0,4);
INSERT INTO my_table (col_1,col_2,col_3) VALUES(3,1,1);
COMMIT;


ALTER TABLE  my_table  ADD total  NUMBER;

UPDATE my_table  SET total=greatest(col_1, col_2, col_3);
--2 rows updated. 
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM my_table ;
```

[image: Result]